# Circular motion with air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

> A mass of object M = 100 g is attached to the end of a string of length R = 20 cm. A person swings the mass overhead such that his hand moves in a circle with radius r = 10 cm with angular velocity ω = 18 rad/s, ahead of the mass M by 90°. Find the force of air resistance on the object.  How do I solve this? I guessed that I should solve the tension on the string first, am I correct?

Comment: Are you sure no other information is provided in the wording of the problem? The way it is stated its hard to tell how air resistance comes into the problem

Comment: Draw a picture with the hand tracing a small circle and the object tracing a large one. Place the object directly overhead and the arm therefore horizontal (90 degrees ahead on their concentric circles). Draw the free-body diagram of the object, with its three forces.  Sketch the acceleration vector; based on the constant angular velocity, the object should not be accelerating along the path. Write down Newton's Second Law; it should give you two equations for the two unknowns: $F_\text{AR}$ and $F_T$. Note that the angle is given by your picture, the speed is given by the angular velocity.

Comment: I should note that I've assumed the object is directly overhead. The FBD, and therefore the answer, will change with position of the object. I'm not sure if it is looking for a more general answer where the tension and air resistance depend on the angular position on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I see for the free-body diagram at an arbitrary angular position, $\varphi$, of the object.

I have no idea if such a dynamic is physically realizable, but I think that this what the question is proposing (constant angular velocity implying constant speed; constant radii for both hand and object; constant 90 degree angular separation of hand and object).

Comment: Thank you. I think I solved the equation, the answer I got is 1.0 N, which appears in the options.

Comment: It didn't mention gravity, so I think it is horizontal circular motion.